# How to get instance of database and close it? Tornado

Tags: python, mysql, tornado

I'm having trouble with MySQL timing out and going away after 8 hours. I am using google app engine as a host. My Python script uses the Tornado framework.

Right now I instantiate my MySQL db connection before any functions right at the top of the main server script. Once I deploy that, the clock starts ticking and 8 hours or so later, MySQL will go away and I will have to deploy my script again.

I haven't been using db.close() at all because I hear that restarting the database connection takes a long time. Is this true? Or is there a proper way to use db.close()?

One of my friends suggested I try getting the database instance and then closing it after each function.. is that recommended and where might I find some tutorials on that?

I'm mostly looking for resources here, but if someone wants to lay it out for me that would be awesome.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The connection is going away because of the `wait_timeout` session variable which
is the number of seconds the server waits for activity on a noninteractive connection 
before closing it.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout

Good way is to close the connection each time and create a new one if you are not reusing the same connection so frequently, otherwise you can increase the value of `wait_timeout`

Comment: should i set this wait time_out in the server script right after i make the database connection? Like so: cur.execute("""SET SESSION wait_timeout = 31536000""")

Comment: yes you can do this to set its value for the current session.

Answer (score 0):

Establishing a connection to a MySQL database should be quite fast and it is certainly good practice to keep the connection open only for as long as you need it.

I am not certain why your connection should be non-responsive for 8 hours - have you tried checking your settings?

The correct command in Python is connection.close().

Comment: So would it be best to simply put connection.close() after each function is finished? i.e. right after self.finish() i do connection.close() ?

And MySQL isn't unresponsive /for/ 8 hours, only /after/ 8 hours since deploying the script.. is this what you meant?